# Angular 6 project not running in ie and edge browser, although all polifile required codes are uncommented

Tags: angular

[image]Angular 6 project not running in ie and edge browser, although all polifile required codes are uncommented

-> showing syntax error while site opening.

Comment: Please give a screenshot of the error.

Comment: could you provide a demo link?

Comment: @Flix yes, please look the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure following packages imported.

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```